# How to Split and Compare Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different Dataframes in pyton like this:

```
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7"], 
                   'BBB' : ["c1","c2","c2","c2","c3","c3","c1"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : ["a1","a2","a4","a6","a7","a8","a9"], 
                    'BBB' : ["c11","c21","c21","c12","c13","c13","c11"]})
```

I want to compare values of `"AAA"` and find the number of similar values based on the `"BBB"` groups.
 for example the similarity between `c1` and `c11` is 1(`a1`)
similarity between `c2`, `c21` is 2(`a2`, `a4`)

In other words, I want to match all row-pairs in `df` and `df2`, for which the string `df2['BBB']` starts with the string `df['BBB']` and of those  matching row-pairs, so as to have all values `df['AAA']` where `df['AAA']` equals `df2['AAA']`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this question at all, can you please reword

Comment: How do you use `CCC`? If you don't, why show it to us?

Comment: I removed  the CCC

Answer (score 0):

The following code calculates the similarities that you want (it does not use the `CCC` column):

```
sims = pd.merge(df,df2,how='outer').\
       groupby(['AAA'])['BBB'].sum().value_counts().reset_index()
#   index  BBB
#0  c2c21    2
#1  c3c12    1
#2  c1c13    1
#3  c1c11    1
#4     c2    1
#5    c11    1
#6     c3    1
#7    c13    1

sims['index'] = sims['index'].str.split('c').str[1:]
sims[sims['index'].str.len() > 1]
#     index  BBB
#0  [2, 21]    2
#1  [3, 12]    1
#2  [1, 13]    1
#3  [1, 11]    1
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be calculated like:

```
# merge both dataframes on column 'AAA' since
# in the end only the rows are of interest
# for which AAA is equal in both frames
merged= df.merge(df2, on='AAA', suffixes=['_df', '_df2'])

# define a function that can be used
# to check the BBB-string of df2 starts
# with the BBB-string of df
def check(o):
    return o['BBB_df2'].startswith(o['BBB_df'])

# apply it to the dataframe to filter the rows    
matches= merged.apply(check , axis='columns')
# now aggregate only the rows to which both
# criterias apply
result= merged[matches].groupby(['BBB_df', 'BBB_df2']).agg({'AAA': ['nunique', set]})
result.columns= ['similarity', 'AAA_values']
result.reset_index()
```

The output is:

```
Out[111]: 
  BBB_df BBB_df2  similarity AAA_values
0     c1     c11           1       {a1}
1     c1     c13           1       {a7}
2     c2     c21           2   {a2, a4}
```

Input data:

```
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : ["a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7"], 
                   'BBB' : ["c1","c2","c2","c2","c3","c3","c1"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : ["a1","a2","a4","a6","a7","a8","a9"], 
                    'BBB' : ["c11","c21","c21","c12","c13","c13","c11"]})
```